# UISearchbar cancel button isn't enabled when search bar isn't first responder

Tags: uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uicontrol, uisearchbardelegate

My UISearchbar has a visible cancel button.

```
self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
```

When I do

```
[self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

the cancel button stops working  (enabled = NO)

I am using this hack to forcefully enable the cancel button (category on `UISearchbar`):

```
-(UIButton *)cancelButton
{
    for (UIView *v in self.subviews) {
        for (UIView *subview in v.subviews) {
            if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            {
                return (UIButton *)subview;
            }
        }
    }
    ELog(@"Couldn't find cancel button");
    return nil;
}
```

But it doesn't seem the legit way to do it. Are there better ways?